# Run jQuery only when previous page was homepage

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies

Basically the homepage has the CSS the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0r261be/1/) starts with, and I want the inner pages to animate to their new CSS class ONLY when visited after the homepage.

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Thank you for your assistance!
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.container {
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.container div {
    background: #eaeaea;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.container.inner,
.container.inner div {
    transition: all 0.75s ease-in;
}

.container.inner {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.container.inner div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ( jQuery(".home").length == 0  ) {
            jQuery('.container').addClass('inner');
        }
    }, 500 );
});
</script>
```

I imagine I need to use a cookie or two to determine if the previous page was the homepage and another to apply CSS without delay or animation if the previous page was an inner page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PHP to determine the document referrer. Thank you @Jai for pointing me in the right direction. I placed the jQuery that changes the CSS inside a separate file and I call that js file whenever the referrer is "index.php" or "/"

Here's the exact code I used (on WordPress functions.php)

```
$homePagePaths = array (
  '/index.php',
  '/'
);

$parts = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if (empty($parts['path']) || in_array($parts['path'], $homePagePaths)) 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'inner-animation', 
  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/inner-animation.js', 
  array('jquery'), '', true )
;
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.referrer` is something you want to look at:

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf('home')){
   // apply the addClass here then.
}
```

Note:
<sub>*`document.referrer` only holds the last page visited.*</sub>

Comment: Thank you, Jai. I will look into that. -- off the bat it didn't work as expected, but I'll keep playing with it some more before I take more of your time.

Comment: I posted an answer using the referrer, but with PHP instead of jQuery. Let me know what you think. Thanks again for your time.